# Solving an equation system in terms of an unknown like z, could use some help in matlab or other programming languages

Tags: python, c, matlab, signal-processing, equation-solving

For example I have been given some equations and the solution is asked in terms of y/x = only numbers and z.

```
w1=-x+w2+w3,
w2=(z^-1)*x+2*w3,
w3=(z^-1)*w2+(z^-1)*y,
y=2*w1
```

I would like to see the solution to be done like this: (y/x = some equation only in terms of z and numbers)

```
y/x=(-2+6*(z^-1)+2*(z^-2))/(1-8*(z^-1))
```

Is there a way to do this? Could be code or some function in certain programming languages like matlab.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about https://www.google.com/search?q=python+solve+equation+system Yes, it is possible to do that in Python.

Comment: Picking a specific language is a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

**MATLAB:**

The [isolate(eqn,expr)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isolate.html) function will do this. The given example is, where x is isolated from `a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0`:

```
syms x a b c
eqn = a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0;
xSol = isolate(eqn, x)
```

Output:

```
xSol =
x == -(b + (b^2 - 4*a*c)^(1/2))/(2*a)
```

**WolframAlpha:**

```
solve(eqn,exp)
```

e.g. `solve(a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0,x)` will also re-write the same equation in terms of x.

Alteratively, a WolframAlpha widget exists to do this manually: https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=3d613c498715c870be91ed38004abc81

Comment: I got the idea but theres something I didnt understand here, this example you shared used only 1 equation while I need to use all of the equations. And I want to isolate all of them as y/x, not x only. Could this be done with this method?